# Using bash and awk to print to a specific column in a new document

Tags: bash, variables, loops, awk

I am trying to use bash and awk together with a nested for loop to print data out into columns beside each other.
so far this is what I have:

```
for k in {1..147..3}
do
for i in "52" "64" "60" "70" "74"
do
        awk -v x="${i}" -F, 'match ($0,x) { print $k }' all.csv > final.csv
done
done
echo "script has run"
```

I need to print out the information into the column k in the new file.. however that does not work.
so in the csv file data is like this:

```
52,9/05,6109
52,9/06,6119
64,9/05,7382
64,9/06,7392
64,9/07,3382
60,9/06,3829
...
```

I want my output like this:

```
52,9/05,6109,64,9/05,7382,60,9/06,3829
52,9/06,6119,64,9/06,7392
,,,64,9/07,3382
```

basically, all the 52s in the first column, the 64s in fourth column, the 60s in seventh column

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `print $k`, use `printf "%s,",$k`.

`printf` is the print formatter function that is common to many languages. `%s` tells it the first argument should be a string.

Note that `awk` won't get the `$k` from the shell, so you'll need to add `-v k=$k`.

Comment: This gives me an error.. but could you please explain what each of those terms mean? i think with the explanation it might help me to understand it better

Comment: awk: (FILENAME=all.csv FNR=21910) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%s'

Comment: That means that either you forgot to add `$k` after the format or your file doesn't have that column and your awk implementation doesn't like printing undefined variables.

Comment: I am printing all this to a new file which has no columns. can the awk function create the columns in the new file?

Comment: The input file (all.csv) is the one that matters. Make sure that you have an argument to printf for every `%` in the format string. If you already do, maybe check if `NF > k` and if so just printf a lone `,`.